# Optimizing vector distances to a certain distribution with Gaussian kernel function

Tags: optimization

Suppose we have a set of vectors on a unit circle $u_i$.
And we use the Gaussian kernel to measure the distance among them, which could be described as:

$$
G(u,v)=e^{-||u-v||_2^2}
$$

One already proved theory is that when we maximize the sum of distances among these vectors, the final result is the uniform distribution on the unit circle. This can be described as:

$$
U_n=\arg\min\limits_{u_1,u_2,...,u_N} \sum_{1\leq i\le j \leq N}{G(u_i,u_j)}
$$

where $U_n$ denotes uniform distribution.

I think by putting weights $\lambda_{ij} \in [0,1]$ for each term $G(u_i,u_j)$ in the above equation, we can get a result of certain distribution. (Here we need to normalize the summation of $\lambda_{ij}$ to ensure that the summation equals to $C_N^2$). For example, we take $\lambda_{12}=0.5$ while other weights remain $1$. Thus, in the final result, $u_1$ and $u_2$ should be closer than other pairs. My question is, can we prove that (even in higher dimensions, not only on a unit circle)?

For the proof of uniform distribution mentioned at the beginning, you may refer to Proposition 4.4.1, Theorem 6.2.1, and Corollary 6.2.2 in Borodachov, S. V., Hardin, D. P., and Saff, E. B. Discrete energy on rectifiable sets. Springer, 2019.

Comment: Don't you mean "maximize the sum of distances"?

Comment: @user619894 Sorry for the typo. Revised.

Comment: Not sure what you want to prove? That for smaller $\lambda$ the pairs are closer? I suppose you might look at $\lambda_{ij} = 0$ and argue from continuity.

Comment: @user619894 Actually I want to prove that the distribution is related to $\lambda_{ij}$. The uniform distribution is a special case since each lambda equals to 1.